# How to show double quote in input tag?

Tags: html, input

How to show double quote in input tag ?

my `$test` is `i test "hello"`

and input like this

```
<input name="test" type="text" value="<?PHP echo $test; ?>">
```

When test code in input show only `i test`

How can i do for show `i test "hello"` in input tag ?

Comment: Use single quotes for the `value` attribute. `value='<?PHP echo $test; ?>'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) or use [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities)

```
<input name="test" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($test); ?>">

<input name="test" type="text" value="<?php echo htmlentities($test); ?>">
```

Or by using PHP **echo** you can do it

```
<?php echo '<input name="test" type="text" value="'.$test.'">'; ?>
```

Comment: The last `echo` will produce `value="i test "hello""`, so that's not going to work.

Answer (score -1):

use `html_entity_decode` since you're using `php` like so:

`<input name="test" type="text" value="<?PHP echo html_entity_decode($test); ?>">`

Comment: I think you mean `htmlentities()`.

Comment: No. That's exactly what I mean. Because `htmlentities` is its opposite